# Infragistics: Document content host "A deferred show is already in progress" when loading layouts with floating tabs

Tags: wpf, infragistics

We are using the infragistics LoadLayout(layout) method to load and save dock managers.  When loading the document content host we get an error that states "A deferred show is already in progress".  This happens when the layout contains a floating pane.  The layout is stored in the database and passed in as a string to the method.  It does not happen always and sometimes will load fine.  I'm assuming it is some type of timing issue but can't find any information on it.  Any suggestions on why this error is occuring?

Comment: Is there a call stack for the exception?

Comment: Our company is experiencing the same issue, did you ever get a resolution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It happens to us as well.  It seems to only occur if the floating pane was never pinned or resized.  If it was pinned or resized then it loads fine.  The xml parameter to watch is "lastFloatingWindowRect".  If it contains NaN,NaN then it will not load correctly.